# What is an object?

Tags: r, object, attributes

Consider the following silly input and output:

```
> names(function(x) x*x)<-"square"
Error in names(function(x) x * x) <- "square" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Implicitly, this error suggests that `function(x) x * x` is an object, but a non-language one. However, the documentation for `names()` says that it allows "*an R object*" as its input, contradicting this premise. Furthermore, [the language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-objects) says "*In R functions are objects*", which confuses matters further. Finally, `is.object(function(x) x * x)` returns `FALSE`, but I think that's for class reasons.

My question is this: What are objects and why does `names()` treat `function(x) x * x` as if it is not one?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but for those who need to, if any, this works : ```assign(x = "square", function(x) x*x)```

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington I don't think that's the same thing. The code in the question is trying to assign the name "square" to the function. I believe that what you've done is to assign the function to the **variable name** "square". I believe that your code is equivalent to `assign("square", function(x) x*x)` i.e. `square<-function(x) x*x`.

Comment: Oh yes, your absolutley right. In your case, do you intend that your code leads to ```square(24)``` as an acceptable code or not ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington No. I'm trying to use the `names` function on an anonymous function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are getting is not due to the nature of a `function` object, but to the fact that the argument of `names<-` is an "anonymous" object and not one which has been linked to a symbol. Consider this:

```
names(1:10)<-letters[1:10]
#Error in names(1:10) <- letters[1:10] : 
#  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Same output. In the error, `non-language` looks like a very convoluted way to say "not a symbol". However, that's pretty logical that you have an error, since you are calling a replacement function and the symbol whose content you asked to replace isn't there. At its root, it has to do with `<-` operator which expects the left hand side of an assignment to be a symbol (a language object) and not a "standard" object:

```
1:10<-setNames(1:10,letters[1:10])
#Error in 1:10 <- setNames(1:10, letters[1:10]) : 
#  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Same error again.

This works, of course:

```
a<-1:10
names(a)<-letters[1:10]
```

Getting to your example:

```
f<-function(x) x*x
names(f)<-"square"
# Error in names(f) <- "square" : names() applied to a non-vector
```

You get the above error if you call explicitly `names<-` with the "anonymous" function:

```
"names<-"(function(x) x*x, "square")
# Error: names() applied to a non-vector
```

Now the error is due to the fact that `names<-`, although a generic, does not have a method for functions. This is documented in `?names`, Details section:

> ‘names’ is a generic accessor function, and ‘names<-’ is a generic
> replacement function.  The default methods get and set the
> ‘"names"’ attribute of a vector (including a list) or pairlist.

I just add a couple of lines regarding the main question: "What is an object". In R, everything is an object. The `is.object` function has a misleading name and a better name should have been `is.internalobjectbitset`. The doc is pretty clear. The title say: "Is an Object 'internally classed'?" and not something like "is a variable an object?"; in the argument section, for `x` it says: `x: object to be tested`, which is rather strange if you want to test whether `x` is an object in the first place. It also specifies that is intended mainly for internal use and not as a way to define what is an object (which would be a silly function, since everything is an object in R).

Following the comments, I'd add that, all in all, the doc misses to state that, while you can apply `names` to any R object, you cannot assign `names` to some types. In my opinion, it's a very minor issue, since `names` are not just an ordinary attribute, but are very linked to some properties of the language and specifically subsetting. Only objects that can be subset can have names. A function object is not meant to be subset and so R prevents to assign a names attribute which would be basically of no use.

Comment: Your answer gives a strong case for the falsehood of `names`'s claim that it expects `x` to be "_an R object_", but you've also shown that `names` is a generic. Could it be that "_an R object_" means "_object_" in the `is.object` sense of the word and the documentation is trying to tell us that `names` can, in theory, work on any such object? I'm unsure if the `names` documentation is wrong, if "_an R object_" is poorly defined, or if the documentation is trying to talk about `is.object` objects. Unhelpfuly, `setNames(1:5,letters[1:5])` is not an `is.object` object, but clearly has names.

Comment: Not sure to get your comment. `names` actually accepts any R object. The replacement gives an error when the user attempts to set names to some types (like functions), which are not intended to have names (and frankly can't see much of a reason for a function to have a name attribute, when it can have any arbitrary additional attribute). The `is.object` function, despite its name, plays no role here and has nothing to do with what an object is in R.

Comment: Does it really count as accepting any R object when some types of object throw errors? The crux of my issue with `names` is that its documentation says that `x` can be "_an R object_", whereas your answer has shown objects where `names` does not work. It is unclear to me if the `names` documentation is wrong or if "_an R object_" is poorly defined. Is your comment distinguishing between `names` and `"names"<-`? Their documentation uses the same `x` argument, so it should not make any difference here?

Comment: I get what you mean. As a fact, `names` accepts anything, while the replacement does not. Strictly speaking, we can say that the doc is wrong, but since names are used for indexing and indexing a function does not make much sense, I think that it is a very very minor issue.

Comment: Expanding from the above, consider also that names are strictly linked with subsetting/indexing, and that's a property of the language itself. Amongst the basic R types, you can assign names to the types you can subset.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [R source code (`names.c`)](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/names.c) :

```
{"is.null",       do_is,        NILSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.logical",    do_is,        LGLSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.integer",    do_is,        INTSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.double",     do_is,        REALSXP,1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.complex",    do_is,        CPLXSXP,1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.character",  do_is,        STRSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.symbol",     do_is,        SYMSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.name",       do_is,        SYMSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.environment",do_is,        ENVSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.list",       do_is,        VECSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.pairlist",   do_is,        LISTSXP,1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.expression", do_is,        EXPRSXP,1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.raw",        do_is,        RAWSXP, 1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},

{"is.object",     do_is,        50,     1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},

{"isS4",          do_is,        51,     1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.numeric",    do_is,        100,    1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.matrix",     do_is,        101,    1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.array",      do_is,        102,    1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.atomic",     do_is,        200,    1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.recursive",  do_is,        201,    1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.call",       do_is,        300,    1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"is.language",   do_is,        301,    1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},

{"is.function",   do_is,        302,    1,  1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
...
```

shows that `objects`(50) are a specific type, different from `function`(302), or other types (`numeric`, `matrix`,...)

This is confirmed in definition of `do_is` in `coerce.c`:

```
    case 50:        /* is.object */
    LOGICAL0(ans)[0] = OBJECT(CAR(args));
    break;
```

Objects have the following methods:

```
/* Objects */
{"inherits",    do_inherits,    0,  11, 3,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"UseMethod",   do_usemethod,   0,     200, -1, {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"NextMethod",  do_nextmethod,  0,     210, -1, {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
{"standardGeneric",do_standardGeneric,0, 201,   -1, {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
```

Which points to base R documentation :

> R possesses a simple generic function mechanism which can be used for an object-oriented style of programming. Method dispatch takes place based on the class(es) of the first argument to the generic function or of the object supplied as an argument to UseMethod or NextMethod.

This shows that objects of type 50, detected by `is.object`, are simply S3 classes or S4 classes, and is confirmed by `is.object` documentation:

> `is.object` - Is an object internally classed? It returns TRUE if the object x has the R internal OBJECT bit set, and FALSE otherwise. The OBJECT bit is set when a "class" attribute is added and removed when that attribute is removed, so this is a very efficient way to check if an object has a class attribute. (S4 objects always should.)

In short : **an internal object has the `class` attribute set**.

This is quite restrictive compared to objects in common language.
Not sure R documentation always means `objects(50)` when speaking about objects.

Regarding `names(function())` error, see clarification by @nicola.

Comment: "_Regarding names(function()) the error considers this objet as a non-language object, which could be understood as not object(50)._" - How do you know this?

Comment: I don't know for sure, hence the conditional form.

Comment: What you say is correct except from the interpretation of the error, which does not depend on the input being a function. See my answer.

Comment: Upon further reading, I think some of the content of this answer is misleading. For instance, "objects(50) are a specific type": that's not true. You have presented that list like each option were mutually exclusive. One object can pass both `is.logical` and `is.object` for instance. The flag 50 is not an intrinsic value of an R object; rather, it's just the argument of `do_is` that tells the function which kind of test to perform.

Answer (score 0):

A syntax error and a poorly worded error message says little about the status of objects in the language. This is a red herring.